# Citing just the first author in text

Tags: citing, harvard-style

I'm writing a paper based on the template of the conference to which I intend to submit it, and it uses the Harvard citation style. In my text, there's a line that is as it follows:

```
    The Linear Quadratic Gaussian/Loop Transfer Recover (LQG/LTR) method, initially addressed by \citeasnoun{kwakernaak_1969} and popularized by \citeasnoun{athans_1986},\citeasnoun{stein_1987} and \citeasnoun{doyle_1981}...
```

The compiled file gives me this text:

"The Linear Quadratic Gaussian/Loop Transfer Recover (LQG/LTR) method, initially addressed by Kwakernaak (1969) and popularized by Athans (1986), Stein and Athans (1987) and Doyle and Stein (1981)..."

Since they are 3 authors collaborating with each other in three articles, is there a way to make my citation command show only the name of the first author of the paper, so each author is mentioned only once in this sentence?

Thanks in advance for any collaboration.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` will behave as you ask for.

You can look up different bibliography styles on [this page](https://sv.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibtex_bibliography_styles).